# Multiply pd DataFrame column with 7-digit scalar

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scalar

I am trying to modify a pandas dataframe column this way:

```
Temporary=DF.loc[start:end].copy()
SLICE=Temporary.unstack("time").copy()
SLICE["Var"]["Jan"] = 2678400*SLICE["Var"]["Jan"]
```

However, this does not work. The resulting column SLICE["Var"]["Jan"] is still the same as before the multiplication.
If I multiply with 2 orders of magnitude less, the multiplication works. Also a subsequent multiplication with 100 to receive the same value that was intended in the first place, works.

```
SLICE["Var"]["Jan"] = 26784*SLICE["Var"]["Jan"]
SLICE["Var"]["Jan"] = 100*SLICE["Var"]["Jan"]
```

I seems like the scalar is too large for the multiplication. Is this a python thing or a pandas thing? How can I make sure that the multiplication with the 7-digit number works directly?

I am using Python 3.8, the precision of numbers in the dataframe is float32, they are in a range between 5.0xE-5 and -5.0xE-5 with some numbers having a smaller absolute value than 1xE-11.

EDIT: It might have to do with the 2-level column indexing. When I delete the first level, the calculation works:

```
Temporary=DF.loc[start:end].copy()
SLICE=Temporary.unstack("time").copy()
SLICE=SLICE.droplevel(0, axis=1)
SLICE["Jan"] = 2678400*SLICE["Jan"]
```

Comment: Yes, you might need to use `.loc` for this.  There are warnings in the documentation that, in some cases, `SLICE["Var"]` returns a temporary, rather than a pointer into the full DataFrame.

Comment: .loc works, thank you. However, I am confused that this error in my case only appears if the scalar has a certain order of magnitude..

Comment: I see it.  I don't know how to explain it.

Answer (score 1):

Your first method might give `SettingWithCopyWarning` which basically means the changes are not made to the actual dataframe. You can use `.loc` instead:

```
SLICE.loc[:,('Var', 'Jan')] =  SLICE.loc[:,('Var', 'Jan')]*2678400
```